# convert http to https in wsdl

Tags: jakarta-ee, https, tomcat7

I am accessing a web-service. I have deployed the war file in tomcat and the wsdl file generated has http link. I need to change it to https(or route it to https).

```
the link is somewhat like this:
http://sdkfjk/services/abcService?wsdl

and I need to have it somewhat like this:
https://sdkfjk/services/abcService?wsdl
```

Do I need to change java code? or some changes in tomcat/conf/server.xml ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to change your code. You should configure HTTPS in Tomcat. The procedure can be found here:

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/ssl-howto.html

You can further lock down your application to demand an HTTPS connection by creating a security constraint in your application's `web.xml`:

```
<web-app>
    <security-constraint>
      <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Secure URLs</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </web-resource-collection>
      <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
      </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
</web-app>
```